# operator in class ("C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations")

Tags: c++

This is the error I'm getting " C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations" I don't know how to fix it

```
//this code id in the DynamicStringArray.cpp
template<class T>
DynamicArray<T>:: operator = (const DynamicArray<T> &rightSide) {
  if(this != &rightSide) {
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    dynamicArray = new T[rightSide.size];
    size = rightSide.size;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      dynamicArray[i] = rightSide.dynamicArray[i];
    }
  }
//and this one is in the DynamicStringArray.h
template <class T>
class DynamicArray{
public:
DynamicArray<T> operator=(const DynamicArray &rightSide);
```

```
exit status 1
DynamicStringArray.cpp:64:19: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
DynamicArray:: operator = (const DynamicArray &rightSide) {
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You forgot the return type. `operator=` should return a reference to the current object. See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) for more details and suggestions.

Comment: Not the answer, but consider [copy&swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). Writing assignment operators becomes a no-brainer in 95% cases.

Comment: Also template code should only be placed in a [header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: And the return type should be a reference, not an object `DynamicArray<T>& operator=(`

Answer (score 0):

> " C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations" I don't know how
>   to fix it

You fix this problem by adding a type specifier to your declaration.  What does the function

```
template<class T>
DynamicArray<T>:: operator = (...)
```

return?  Probably not an int or float or bool, right?  The compiler does not know because you did not identify what the return type is.

Here is an example (I found in SO!):

```
// In MyClass.h
MyClass<T>&    operator+=(const MyClass<T>& classObj);


// In MyClass.cpp
template <class T>
MyClass<T>&    MyClass<T>::operator+=(const MyClass<T>& classObj) {
  // ...
  return *this;
}
```

In both cases, the return type specifier is simply:

```
MyClass<T>&
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And the " return *this; " is hopefully quite clear.